# process requests with user thread pool grpc

Tags: c++, multithreading, grpc

I was going through this [async_server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.24.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc) example. I am interested in the following code snippet,

```
while (true) {
  // Block waiting to read the next event from the completion queue. The
  // event is uniquely identified by its tag, which in this case is the
  // memory address of a CallData instance.
  // The return value of Next should always be checked. This return value
  // tells us whether there is any kind of event or cq_ is shutting down.
  GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
  GPR_ASSERT(ok);
  /*
    How to enqueue this request on an existing thread pool
    For example,
    pool.enqueue() {
         /* what to enqueue so that when one worker thread of my thread pool
         pop one requests it can decide what handler to execute */
    }
  */
  
  // do not process request in this thread, commenting it
  // static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
}
```

In my design, the above loop is executed by one dedicated thread and this thread basically pushes requests into a `thread-safe` queue. The worker threads in the pool pop request objects from the `thread_safe` queue and processes requests in parallel in a multi-core environment.

I have a few simple handler functions and these are supposed to be triggered for a specific request popped out of the queue by a worker thread. The object that is going to be pushed into the queue should have enough information so that the worker thread can decide what handler to execute.

For example; handler functions can be very simple CPU bound tasks.

```
void handler1( .... some argument ) {
    // a CPU bound for loop
    // reply someting to the client }
```

**My question is:** How to enqueue the tag information into the user-defined `thread_safe` queue, assuming the thread_safe queue provides the following API:

```
enqueue(someObj task) {
     // task should have tag information required for the worker threads to select 
     // proper handler function.
     // I need to know the following, what should I push to the queue or what 
     // other code changes I need to do to push something meaningful for the 
     // worker threads. Should I create multiple services? Or can I handle 
     // multiple handler functions by having the same service. 
}
```

When I say `handler function` I mean the following w.r.t the existing code in the [async_server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.24.0/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc) link.

```
    // inside proceed() function
    // The actual processing.
    
    std::string prefix("Hello ");
    reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());
```

Thank You.